# C++ Grouping repetitions within Vector

Tags: c++, vector, grouping, repeat

I've got a file structured like this:

```
A 123456 0
G 123456 5
A 235334 0
B 123456 2
```

Each piece of information is being stored like so:

```
temp.code >> temp.personid >> temp.data
```

I've stored this information in a Vector

```
 ifstream fin("test.txt");
 vector<TestClass> test;
 TestClass temp;
 string line;
 while (getline(fin, line)) {//.. test.push_back(temp);}
```

A given *personid* can come up numerous times within the file.
What I want to do is iterate through the vector and group the repetitions into a single class object per *personid*, my goal is that I want sum the data for each particular object such that the output for the file above would be:

```
123456 : 7
235334 : 0
```

What would be an elegant way to approach this?

Thanks

Comment: How about [a map](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map) with the `personid` as the key and the *accumulated* `data` as data?

Comment: You can use a map, with the key being the type of `personid` and the value being the type of `data`.

Comment: would not multimap be better approach here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code uses an [`std::unordered_map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map) as suggested by the comments already. It will read your file line by line.
The code assumes that the person's id is of type `int`, the code of type `std::string` and the data of type `int`.

It inserts every `Person` (here as example a struct) into the map. If a person's id is already there it will sum up the data. That means that this solution doesn't use a temporary `std::vector` but only the `std::unordered_map`.

[See live example with your data on ideone.com](https://ideone.com/HhTzaj).

**Code:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>

struct Person
{
   std::string code;
   int         data;
};

typedef std::unordered_map<int, Person> PersonMap;

int main()
{
   std::ifstream fin("test.txt");

   PersonMap persons;

   /* line by line reading */
   for (std::string line; std::getline(fin, line); )
   {
      std::istringstream iss(line);

      int    personId;
      Person personData;

      /* parse line as std::string, int, int */
      iss >> personData.code >> personId >> personData.data;

      /* insert into map and save result */
      std::pair<PersonMap::iterator, bool> insertResult =
         persons.insert(std::pair<int, Person>(personId, personData));

      /* if personId is already there */
      if (!insertResult.second)
      {
         insertResult.first->second.data += personData.data;
      }
   }

   /* output whole map */
   for(auto const &person : persons)
   {
      std::cout << person.first << " : " << person.second.data << "\n";
   }
   std::cout << std::flush;
}
```

**Output:**

> ```
> 235334 : 0
> 123456 : 7
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Use [Unordered map](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map). The lookup time in the unordered map is constant **`O(1)`** in average case. I have used vector for sample data, you can load data from a file instead of the vector.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    unordered_map<string, int>m;
    unordered_map<string, int>::iterator itr;    // Iterator to iterate unordered map
    vector<pair<string, int> >person_details;    // pair of vector to represent sample data, you can load data from file instead
    person_details.push_back(make_pair("123456",0));
    person_details.push_back(make_pair("123456",5));
    person_details.push_back(make_pair("235334",0));
    person_details.push_back(make_pair("123456",2));
    for(int i=0;i<person_details.size();i++)
    {
        if(m.find(person_details[i].first) == m.end() )                // If personId is not present in map, insert it
            m[person_details[i].first]=person_details[i].second;
        else m[person_details[i].first]+=person_details[i].second;        // If personId is present in map, increment it.
    }
    for(itr=m.begin();itr!=m.end();itr++)          
        cout<<itr->first<<" "<<itr->second<<endl;       // Displaying personId with occurance
    return 0;
}

Output:
235334 0
123456 7
```

Note: You can use [Map](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) to have constant **`O(LogN)`** time, where **N** is the size of container.

Comment: `The complexity of lookup for std::unordered_map is O(1) (constant) in the average case, and O(N) (linear) in the worst case.` taken from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16068151/c-stl-map-is-access-time-o1

Comment: Keep in mind that O(1) does *not* equal faster execution. Sometimes iterating over a small vector is faster even though it is a linear search

Comment: @AndreKampling Thanks, I have updated the answer. `Worst case only occurs in case of too many hash collisions`.